# angular typescript error using model with nested object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 6 with the HttpClient

This is the result i get when i do a search call to the OMDB api:

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End","Year":"2007","imdbID":"tt0449088","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyNjkxNzEyMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjc3MDE3._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"This Is the End","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt1245492","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQxODE3NjM1Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzkzNjc4OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The World's End","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt1213663","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzA1MTk1MzY0OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjkzNTUwMDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Seeking a Friend for the End of the World","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt1307068","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4MDQ1NzE3N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjA0MDkzNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"House at the End of the Street","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt1582507","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTUwNTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTE0MTI3Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The End of the F***ing World","Year":"2017–","imdbID":"tt6257970","Type":"series","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzhhMTczMDQtNWE0Yy00OTJiLTlmYjgtNWU1MmVkYTVlYWVhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjEwNTM2Mzc@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"John Dies at the End","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt1783732","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUyNzIyNzc0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTM5ODg1OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The End of the Tour","Year":"2015","imdbID":"tt3416744","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUwODU3NjQxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODE2NTE4NTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Neon Genesis Evangelion: The End of Evangelion","Year":"1997","imdbID":"tt0169858","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYmE1ZTFjZTMtMDVjYy00ZWYwLTg2ZGUtODhhODgxMjdhYjAxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzM4MjM0Nzg@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The End of the Affair","Year":"1999","imdbID":"tt0172396","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYzhkNDRkMDctYTcxMy00MTI3LWI5ODQtZWNkYWQ2ZjA2ZDk2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"1311","Response":"True"}
```

This results consists of Search(object with results), totalResults(string) and response(string).

The search function in my service file:

```
search(term: string): Observable<Result[]> {

    const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com?s=${term}&apikey=12345`; 

    return this.http.get<Result[]>(url).pipe(
        map(search => search.Search),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

The application works fine. The problem is the typescript compiler gives this error:

```
Property 'Search' does not exist on type 'Result[]'.
```

I can't find a way to deal with the response the OMDB api gives me. Model looks like this:

```
export class Result {
    totalResults: number;
    Response: boolean;
    Search: {
        Poster: string;
        Title: string;
        Type: string;
        Year: number;
        imdbID: string;
    };
}
```

Comment: Just add ``map((search:Result)=> search.Search)`` and error will be resolved.

Comment: @DevangNaghera that would defeat the whole purpose of using interfaces

Comment: @bugs Updated the code :)

Comment: @DevangNaghera Your first suggestion `code` map((search:any)=> search.Search) worked fine, however i think it would be better to define the type. 

Your current solution gives this error: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Result, { Poster: string; Title: string; Type: string; Year: number; imdbID: str...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Result[],

Answer (score 0):

Property `Search` is an Array. Edit your function `search(term: string)` to `search(term: array)`.

Comment: That's not correct. That parameter is used for the input the user types with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The http request will return a `Result[]`. The error is saying that there is no `Result[].Search` which is true.

You can do something like this.

```
map((results: Result[]) => results.map((result:Result) => result.Search))
```

`results.map` refers to [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and not the RxJs one;

You will also need to extract the `Search` interface/class and return `Observable<Search[]>`

Comment: That looked good however i got this:

`Type 'Observable<{ Poster: string; Title: string; Type: string; Year: number; imdbID: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Result[]>'.`

Comment: You want to return Observable<Search []>